# Missing web/index.html_bootstrap.dart.js at dart-polymer project

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a dart project using polymer. When I call pub build or select "Run as JavaScript" on `web/index.html` the generated `build/web/index.html` has the following line at the end:

```
<script src="index.html_bootstrap.dart.js" async=""></script>
```

But I can't find `index.html_bootstrap.dart.js` anywhere.

From my `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  browser: 'any'
  core_elements: '>=0.6.0+4 <0.7.0'
  paper_elements: '>=0.6.1 <0.7.0'
  polymer: '>=0.15.5 <0.16.0'
  polymer_expressions: '>=0.13.0+1 <0.14.0'
transformers:
- $dart2js:
    $include: lib/*.dart
    csp: true
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
    csp: true
```

How and when is `index.html_bootstrap.dart.js` generated?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR this script selects if Dart or JS source should be loaded but `pub build` doesn't support Dart ouput for client code yet.

I think this transformer removes this tag https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_to_js_script_rewriter (didn't try it myself yet)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by $dart2js transformer, remove this transformer and then build again.

```
dependencies:
  browser: 'any'
  core_elements: '>=0.6.0+4 <0.7.0'
  paper_elements: '>=0.6.1 <0.7.0'
  polymer: '>=0.15.5 <0.16.0'
  polymer_expressions: '>=0.13.0+1 <0.14.0'
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
    csp: true
```

or put $dart2js after polymer transformer:

```
dependencies:
  browser: 'any'
  core_elements: '>=0.6.0+4 <0.7.0'
  paper_elements: '>=0.6.1 <0.7.0'
  polymer: '>=0.15.5 <0.16.0'
  polymer_expressions: '>=0.13.0+1 <0.14.0'
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
    csp: true
- $dart2js:
   $include: web/index.html_bootstrap.dart
```

Comment: $dart2js transformer is executed,  no matter if it is included in the pubspec.yaml file or not. Usually the order of transformers in pubspec.yaml is relevant but not for $dart2js (since a while)

Comment: I don't know why, but when I put $dart2js after polymer transformer it compiles index.html_bootstrap.dart to index.hml_bootstrap.dart.js. If I don't do that, index.html_bootstrap.dart is never compiled.

Comment: Interesting. What Dart version do you use (`dart --version` on command line)?

Comment: I tested on windows and linux, and both gave me the same result.

Comment: It's possible that 1.8.5 doesn't yet contain the change. In this case `$dart2js` has to be the last transformer in the list. I assume 1.9.0 will be out soon. Would be interesting if the position of `$dart2js` still matters.